# How to fix 'Mobile devices doesn't populate json events'

Tags: mobile

For some reason calendar doesn't populate json events on mobile devices.

I tried this page using Chrome and Safari for iPhone 7 but it doesn't work properly.

````
countExtra = 0;
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>',
      editable: false,
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: {
        url: '/wp-content/themes/bridge-child/calendar/routines.php?categories=<?=$_GET["categories"]?>&q=<?=$_GET["q"]?>',
        failure: function() {
          jQuery("#errorMessage").css("display", "block");
        }
      },
      loading: function(bool) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = bool ? 'block' : 'none';
      }
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```javascript
I don't see any error messages.
````

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

For some reason Safari is conflicting with the date format so I had to change **2019-01-01 10:00:00** to **2019-01-01T10:00:00**

Just add a *T* between the date and time.

After that, Safari and all mobile browsers started working :)